# How to draw vertical line between RecyclerView elements and also within element?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Here is screenshot

[image]

You can see on the screenshot `RecyclerView` with a different type of the elements.

Question is: How to connect consistently each element by vertical line (as you can see on the right side of the screenshot)?

Also there is a question about the vertical line that consist within one of the `RecyclerView` element (as you can see on the screenshot). Height of the line should be able to dynamically change according of the number of elements that it lead(you can see blue line and bullets on it).

Fell free to ask

Appreciate any kind of ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ItemDecorator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration)
 1) Override method onDraw(...)
 2) find interested views via recycler.getChildAt()
 3) if you need view holder to check type, you can get it via getChildViewHolder
 4) draw vertical line within bounds of view

Comment: Could you please show me implementation how "draw vetical line within bounds of view"?